# Returns to orginal view after segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue, unwind-segue

I have a view controller, after a button is pressed I want it to unwind to the original table view controller and then let it segue into another view controller. 
I don't segue directly to the new view controller because I want that when the back button gets pressed it returns to the original table view controller.
But when I do this it loads the view controller where it's supposed to end, but directly after that it directly returns to the original table view controller

This is my setup in storyboard:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6JKE.jpg

And this is the code I use to make it  happen. 
I call this code in the view controller where the button gets pressed:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("unwindChooseHome", sender: nil)
```

And this code inside the original table view controller:

```
@IBAction func unwindChooseHome(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("destination", sender: nil)
}
```

Hopefully you understand my question I am not native. I don't really know what I am doing wrong maybe there's a totally different way to make this happen.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine that the problem is that you're triggering the "destination" segue prior to the completion of the unwind segue.

Instead of triggering the "destination" segue immediately inside of the unwind action method, try setting a flag on the original view controller that you can then check in `viewDidAppear:` and trigger the segue at that point.

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion worked, I added a property that says wether or not it should transition to the destination or not. This is set to true when the unwind segue occurs  and  then inside the ViewDidAppear it calls performSegueWithIdentifier because it's true.